# Max value with ALL operator in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

### There are two tables:

```
Movie(mID int, title text, year int, director text);
Rating(rID int, mID int, stars int, ratingDate date);
```

I want to make a query with ALL operator where I get the title of the movie and max stars that this movie received.

### I have tried the following:

```
SELECT Title, Stars
FROM Movie m, Rating rt
WHERE m.mID=rt.mID AND stars>=all(SELECT stars FROM rating rt, movie m WHERE m.mid=rt.mid);
```

### I get the error:

> Error: near "all": syntax error

I can't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: It **is** valid SQL, so I guess SQLite simply doesn't support this (unrelated, but: you should really avoid those outdated, ancient implicit joins in the `where` clause and get used to an explicit `join` operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ALL operator in SQLite.

Your query, if it worked, would return only those movies that have the most stars.
This could be simply implemented with MAX():

```
SELECT Movie.title,
       Rating.stars
FROM Movie
JOIN Rating USING (mID)
WHERE Rating.stars >= (SELECT MAX(stars)
                       FROM Rating);
```

If you want the largest number of stars for *every* movie, just use grouping:

```
SELECT Movie.title,
       MAX(Rating.stars) AS stars
FROM Movie
LEFT JOIN Rating USING (mID)
GROUP BY mID;
```

(The [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) also returns movies without ratings.)

The same could also be implemented with a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT title,
       (SELECT MAX(stars)
        FROM Rating
        WHERE mID = Movie.mID
       ) AS stars
FROM Movie;
```